# How to change the name of the element in the xml formed from one xsd to an element defined in another xsd when marshalling using jaxb

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling

I am creating a XBRL instance report from the schema downloaded from the XBRL site. The  element "item" which is of the complex type anyType which is defined in the xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd.

Below is one of the types applicable for the "item" element,

Monetary Item type one of the complex types applicable for "item" element.

```
<complexType name="monetaryItemType" final="extension">
  <simpleContent>
    <extension base="xbrli:monetary">
      <attributeGroup ref="xbrli:numericItemAttrs"/>
    </extension>
 </simpleContent>
</complexType>
```

Below is the part of the schema which gives the type for "item" and the root element.

```
<element name="item" type="anyType" abstract="true">
  <annotation>
    <documentation>
      Abstract item element used as head of item substitution group
    </documentation>
 </annotation>
</element>
<element name="tuple" type="anyType" abstract="true">
 <annotation>
  <documentation>
      Abstract tuple element used as head of tuple substitution group
  </documentation>
 </annotation></element>
<element name="xbrl">
  <annotation>
    <documentation>
      XBRL instance root element.
    </documentation>
  </annotation>
<complexType>
  <sequence>
    <element ref="link:schemaRef" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <element ref="link:linkbaseRef" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <element ref="link:roleRef" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <element ref="link:arcroleRef" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <element ref="xbrli:item"/>
       <element ref="xbrli:tuple"/>
       <element ref="xbrli:context"/>
       <element ref="xbrli:unit"/>
       <element ref="link:footnoteLink"/>
     </choice>
   </sequence>
   <attribute name="id" type="ID" use="optional"/>
   <anyAttribute namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" processContents="lax"/>           
 </complexType>
</element>
```

The "item" element of the above schema should have the name of either of the elements in the below mentioned  external schema

Below is an excerpt from the external schema.

```
 <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://sbr.gov.au/icls/baf/bafot/bafot.02.12.data"    elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://sbr.gov.au/fdtn/sbr.02.15.dtyp" schemaLocation="../../../fdtn /dtyp.sbr.02.15.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://sbr.gov.au/fdtn/sbr.01.02.tech" schemaLocation="../../../fdtn/tech.sbr.01.02.xsd"/>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd"/>

<xsd:element name="bafotAbstract" id="bafot.02.12_bafotAbstract" type="xbrli:stringItemType"  substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" abstract="true" xbrli:periodType="instant"/>
<xsd:element name="FinancialRisk.AdjustmentAndExclusionStatus.Indicator" id="DE13052" type="xbrli:booleanItemType" block="substitution" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" xbrli:periodType="instant"/>
<xsd:element name="FinancialRisk.AdjustmentStatus.Indicator" id="DE12828" type="xbrli:booleanItemType" block="substitution" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" xbrli:periodType="instant"/>
<xsd:element name="FinancialRisk.AggregationBenefit.Amount" id="DE12829" type="xbrli:monetaryItemType" block="substitution" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" xbrli:balance="debit" xbrli:periodType="instant"/>
<xsd:element name="FinancialRisk.AggregationBenefitLifeBusiness.Amount" id="DE12830" type="xbrli:monetaryItemType" block="substitution" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" xbrli:balance="debit" xbrli:periodType="instant"/>
<xsd:element name="FinancialRisk.APRAApprovedAdjustmentsToLMICRC.Amount" id="DE12831" type="xbrli:monetaryItemType" block="substitution" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" xbrli:balance="credit" xbrli:periodType="instant"/>
<xsd:element name="FinancialRisk.CatastropheReinsuranceEnd.Date" id="DE13050" type="xbrli:dateItemType" block="substitution" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true"        
<xsd:element name="FinancialRisk.CatastropheReinsuranceStart.Date" id="DE13051" type="xbrli:dateItemType" block="substitution" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" xbrli:periodType="instant"/>
<xsd:element name="FinancialRisk.ChargeAdjustment.Amount" id="DE12832" type="xbrli:monetaryItemType" block="substitution" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" xbrli:balance="credit" xbrli:periodType="instant"/>
<xsd:element name="FinancialRisk.CumulativeExposuresAdjustment.Amount" id="DE12863" type="xbrli:monetaryItemType" block="substitution" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" xbrli:balance="credit" xbrli:periodType="instant"/>
<xsd:element name="FinancialRisk.DeductionsForNetPremiumsLiability.Amount" id="DE12864" type="xbrli:monetaryItemType" block="substitution" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" xbrli:balance="credit" xbrli:periodType="instant"/>
<xsd:element name="FinancialRisk.DeterminationBasis.Code" id="DE13053" type="dtyp.02.15:sbrDeterminationBasisCodeItemType" block="substitution" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" xbrli:periodType="instant"/>
```

How can I change the name of the item element in the resultant xml to either of the element names from the external schema.I am not sure as to how this can be achieved, please help on this. Down loading all the external schema s and generating types and instantiating them to be added as an item is one option but it is not feasible because of the number and the size of such external schema. Is there some other way to achieve the same.

Comment: This is more of a Java/JAXB question than an XML question. You need to provide the Java code that you have attempted to use. (and please focus on the part with the actual problem - both in the Java code you post and in the code you have already posted, it is very hard to extra your actual question from among all the irrelevant parts.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, I may not be able to post the java code here but i haved edited my question to be specific to issue.